# What Model to Choose for a NN with a Very Wide Output Layer?

Tags: neural-network, linear-regression

The input of my neural network consists of 20 features, whereas the output consists of 20,000 of them (predicting a "quantum classical shadow" based on a few parameters: the rotation angle as the input and a few hundreds of shots of random measurements as the output). AFAIK, it's a linear regression problem.
What I've tried:

- an FCNN (doesn't work good);
- Scikit-Learn Lasso (the same results);
- MSE regression using Neural Tangents (the same).
  Any ideas on how to solve this?
  Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you try to predict only a few of the outputs first. Once you manage to predict good enough 1 or 2 outputs, maybe it will help to come up with a solution to the original task.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/123414/8560, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76984579/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/161778/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I'll try. However, those 20,000 features are a single whole, so I'm not sure it'll succeed. Thanks anyway:-)!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find the solution! A model that can do it is a transformer. Here's a paper on such a model doing just this job:
[Predicting Properties of Quantum Systems with Conditional Generative Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.16943)

Comment: I wish you the best of luck. Please update if you do see good results with this, though.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, it works:-). Transformers are good at handling such wide layers. Didn't know they can be used for such a task, though.